# Which Stack Exchange website to ask about user friendliness

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a couple color pickers that I'm not sure which one is the most user friendly, and looks best. Which Stack Exchange website can I ask that?

Comment: This sounds subjective, which would be poor for any site.

Comment: This sounds more like a forum style post

Comment: Sounds like [ux.se] to me.

Comment: This question is so almost yet completely not racist.

Comment: You can NOT ask about User Friendliness on Stack Exchange, since every moderator here seems HELL BENT upon downgrading ANY question which doesn't fit their narrow definition of a good question. 
They are specifically keen on NOT helping anyone formulating a GOOD question. Reactions are often very swift.
his site has a ***PERVERSE  INCENTIVE*** of rewarding downgraders. This might also be a **cultural** issue, specific to this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com) includes usability and many specific factors that go into designing a user interface.  That's not *exactly* "user-friendliness", but if you can specify what you mean by that, you could probably ask your questions there.

Bad: "How do I make my web page user-friendly?"  Broad, vague, opinion-based.

Better: "I am designing a web site for (this type of user) who have (this type of constraints).  I need them to be able to do (these kinds of tasks) while using (this kind of device).  I have (these technologies) available.  How do I best meet their needs within (this budget/schedule)?"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Here's a link to the question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/88055/most-user-friendly-color-picker (Hope I got it right :)